# Haskell - Parallel list to tuples

Tags: list, haskell, parallel-processing, tuples

I have a function that turns a list to a list of tuples where every key has a value of one. I want to do this by using parallelism. Should `par` an `pseq` in the `parMap` function or in the `main_`?

```
parMap :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
parMap [] = []
parMap (k:xs) = do
        b <- par (k, 1)
        bs <- parMap xs
        return (b:bs)

map_ :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
map_ [] = []
map_ (k:xs) = (k, 1) : map_ xs


main_ = do list <- getWords "test.txt"
       print $ M.toList $ reduce $ group $ map_ list
```

Comment: This operation can't actually be significantly parallelized working with Haskell's linked lists.  "Evaluating `(k, 1)` in parallel" implies that there's more work to do in evaluating `(k, 1)` -- which is essentially zero -- than in initiating parallelism, which will be significantly more expensive.

Comment: @LouisWasserman OK, I was just trying to see how far I can get on my own. It's a linked list, it just a list. How can parallelize the `map_` function?

Comment: I mean, you can "parallelize it," but the parallel version will always be slower than the sequential version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is quite close to this way of defining `parMap`:

```
parMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> Eval [b]
parMap f [] = return []
parMap f (a:as) = do
   b <- rpar (f a)
   bs <- parMap f as
   return (b:bs)
```

To use it, call `runEval` on the resulting `Eval` monad, e.g.:

```
main = do list <- getWords "test.txt"
          let pairs = runEval $ parMap (\x -> (x,1)) list
          ...
```

Update: It looks like `rpar` and `rseq` is just another way of utilizing `par` and `pseq` as a monad. The reason I used it is because they are well documented in the book [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026365.do) and the [parconc package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parconc-examples). You may also be able to find earlier revisions of the book content for free on the Web.

Comment: Thanks! Whats the difference between rpar and par?